# How are beans correctly used and what do they represent?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Good day,

I am trying to use Spring framework in my java project and currently I am configuring the beans.xml file. I am new to Spring and I have difficulties on understanding how beans are used and what do they represent; I have read several documentations but still I need some clarification on this. Can anyone briefly explain what beans are and how are they used? Let's say, I have the following classes; what are beans in this case?

```
public class Repository {

private final Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<Integer>();
private final Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();

public void addInt(int i) {
    integers.add(i);
}

public void addString(String s) {
    strings.add(s);
}

public Set<Integer> getInts() {
    return integers;
}

public Set<String> getStrings() {
    return strings;
}
}
```

and

```
public class Service {

private Repository repository;

public void createInt(int i) {
    repository.addInt(i);
}

public void createString(String s) {
    repository.addString(s);
}

public Set<Integer> getInts() {
    return repository.getInts();
}

public Set<String> getStrings() {
    return repository.getStrings();
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: JavaBeans are reusable software components for Java. They are classes that encapsulate many objects into a single object (the bean). They are serializable, have a 0-argument constructor, and allow access to properties using getter and setter methods.
Give google a try, people say it's good ;-)

Comment: Cheers mate! That means that in my case I have no beans, is that right? I do not have any objects except the Repository which is not serializable

Comment: If it isn't serializable you would get troubles when you use it as bean. So, yeah, it's just another Java Object :-)

Comment: Hmmm, what if instead of <String> and <Integer> I would use serializable objects? Would those sets be considered as beans? Sorry for so many questions :D

Comment: The Sets wouldn't. The Repository would.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, that gave me some explanation on beans!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not forced to use XML configuration, I'd recommend to use at least Spring `4.0.0` and make use of annotation based configuration with `@Configuration @Bean`.

In this case, a "Bean" can be any class you want to be spring managed. A Service, a DAO, whatever.